# String-formatting two zipped NumPy arrays in Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I would like to use pythons format function to print subsequent numbers of a numpy array.

I have got two numpy arrays, let's say:

```
x=[1 2 3 4]
y=[5 6 7 8]
```

Now I would like to print this:

```
1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
```

I can almost achieve this by:

```
print('{} {} {} {}'.format(*zip(x,y)))
```

but it yields:

```
(1,5) (2,6) (3,7) (4,8)
```

Of course I could use

```
"{} {} {} {}".format(x[0], y[0], x[1], y[1])
```

and so on but this requires to know the length of the array.

*Note:*
This line of code does what I want

```
print(*["%f %f"%(a,b) for a,b in zip(x,y)])
```

but this does use the old formatting style and I would like to know if it's possible with the new one, too. It also looks a little bit funky, I think :-D

Comment: So use `print(*["{} {}".format(a, b) for a,b in zip(x,y)])`. You are 99% of the way there. You can drop the list: `print(*("{} {}".format(a, b) for a,b in zip(x,y)))`

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

```
x=[1, 2, 3, 4]
y=[5, 6, 7, 8]

result = ' '.join([str(i) for e in  zip(x, y) for i in e])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to interleave the elements from both lists:

```
list(chain.from_iterable(zip(x, y)))
[1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8]
```

And if you want to print all elements joined as you specify you can do:

```
print(*chain.from_iterable(zip(x, y)))
1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
```

Answer (score 1):

what about some **numpy**

```
np.array(list(zip(a,b))).flatten()
```

**output**

```
array([1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip()` to iterate through two iterables at the same time.

```
l1 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
l2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
    print(i)
    print(j)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible with [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
>>> print(*starmap("{} {}".format, zip(x, y)))
1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
```

Normally, the method given by @yatu with `itertools.chain` is the way to go, especially if you want all elements to be separated by spaces. But `starmap` could come handy when you'd want to have some special formatting between the pairs, for example:

```
>>> print(*starmap("{}:{}".format, zip(x, y)))
1:5 2:6 3:7 4:8
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use numpy, what about

```
>>> ' '.join(np.vstack((x, y)).T.flatten().astype(str))
'1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8'
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing another into the mix

```
("{} "*len(x)*2).format(*np.ravel(list(zip(x,y))))

 '1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8 '
```